# Error message from NULL

Tags: c, raspberry-pi

I'm working through the book *C in a nutshell* and it's really great so far. But now I'm trying to run the following program on my RPi and I come across the following error:

```
include <stdio.h>
int test_func( char *s )
{
        if( s == NULL ) {
                fprintf( stderr,
                        "%s: recieved null pointer argument\n", __func__ );
                return -1;
        }
        /* ... */
}
```

Error:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.6/../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x34): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What does this mean?

Comment: well do you have a main function? How is it supposed to create an executable without an entry point?

Comment: Ahh...that must be my problem. You guys must see that so much :p I'm sorry for posting this.

Comment: You need call `int test_func( char *s )` in the main function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a main function in every C program! Otherwise the program don't know where to start! So this should work:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int test_func( char *s ) {
        if( s == NULL ) {
                fprintf( stderr,
                        "%s: recieved null pointer argument\n", __func__ );
                return -1;
        }
        /* ... */
}

int main() {

    //test_func(str)  call the function with the required parameters

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: @MattMcNabb yep Thanks for the notice! (Yes str must be defined, but i think OP has already a Array in his full code, so he only have to change the name an remove the //)

Comment: Darn, this was back on page 4 and I didn't remember it saying it. That's neat about C. In Comp. Sci. class they've been teaching us to write everything as functions and then re-use it and call it all in a main function. It seems there are more similarities between each "different" programming language than we're led on to believe at first. Like I see learning C as useful because it seems a lot of what Python or any other language does is just call programs written in C to do things, so I don't have to learn C but Python. Neat but strange at the same time.